# Type information is lost when working with high-kinded objects in Scala

Tags: scala, type-inference, higher-kinded-types

I am trying to factorize some code and ended up having to work with higher-kinded types.
The following minimal example works fine:

```
trait Builder[M[_]] {
    def build[A]: M[A]
    def buildPair[A, B]: (M[A], M[B]) = (build[A], build[B])
}

class List[A]

class BuilderList extends Builder[List] {
    def build[A] = new List[A]
}

val l: List[String] = (new BuilderList).build[String]

val ll: (List[String], List[Double]) = (new BuilderList).buildPair[String, Double]

defined trait Builder
defined class List
defined class BuilderList
l: List[String] = List@5c7754a7
ll: (List[String], List[Double]) = (List@62874648,List@7b0f6537)
```

If I now want to apply this to a type with two type arguments, say

```
class Map[K, V]
```

I would like to be able to write

```
trait BuilderMap[K] extends Builder[Map[K, _]] {...}
```

but of course this does not work because type arguments in Scala are not curried.

I found that the following trick allowed me to pass compilation:

```
trait PartialApplier[F[_, _], K] {
    type PartiallyApplied[_] = F[K, _]
}

class BuilderMap[K] extends Builder[PartialApplier[Map, K]#PartiallyApplied] {
    def build[V] = new Map[K, V]
}
```

But then, some strange effect happens and I can't figure out the reason why:

```
scala> val m: Map[Int, String] = (new BuilderMap[Int]).build[String]
m: Map[Int,String] = Map@71da0c64

scala> val mm: (Map[Int, String], Map[Int, Double]) = (new BuilderMap[Int]).buildPair[String, Double]
<console>:21: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Map[Int, _], Map[Int, _])
 required: (Map[Int,String], Map[Int,Double])
   val mm: (Map[Int, String], Map[Int, Double]) = (new BuilderMap[Int]).buildPair[String, Double]
```

It seems that the functions defined in the higher-kinded trait `Builder` lose some type information when I use the `PartialApplier` trick.

Is there a way to make all this work smoothly together? Maybe the `PartialApplier` trick is not the right way to go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example in `type PartiallyApplied[_] = F[K, _]` the underscores don't specify the same type.

It works, if you define `PartialApplier` as

```
trait PartialApplier[F[_, _], K] {
  type PartiallyApplied[V] = F[K, V]
}
```

---

Also, you may avoid using `PartialApplier` at all, and define `Builder` type parameter like this:

```
class BuilderMap[K] extends Builder[({ type L[V] = Map[K, V] })#L] {
  def build[V] = Map.empty[K, V]
}
```

Comment: That is a perfect answer. Thanks!